# can you help me resolve the error "can't assign to function call"?

Tags: python-3.x

whenever i am performing a arithmetic function with the elements of list by converting them to int like

```
for i in range(n):     
  for j in range(i+1):         
      int(l[i])=i*int(m[i])-int(m[j])     
       print(l)
```

i get the error "can't assign to function call" can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

`int(l[i])` is returning a value already and you are trying to assign another value to it, hence the error.

What you should do is:

```py
l[i]=int(i*int(m[i])-int(m[j]))
```